# Number of positive integer solutions of $a+b+c+d=26$ where $a>b$.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I am given the answer is $1078$.

Comment: integral solutions or integer solutions?

Comment: @imranfat: They’re synonymous, so both are correct.

Comment: hmmm, ok I didn't know that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First give one to all 4.

Number of distributions such that $a=b$ is $$\sum_{i=0}^{11}{22-2i+2-1\choose2-1}=\sum_{i=0}^{11}(23-2i)=144$$

Number of distributions so that $a>b$=Number of distributions so that $a<b=x$(say)

Total number of distributions $${22+4-1\choose 4-1}=2300=144+2x\implies x=1078$$

Comment: Yes thanks.I was confused whether to add zero

Comment: @Harish Hope confusion is cleared..Please accept if you like my solution..

Comment: Yes now it's cleared thanks

Comment: @Harish You know how to **accept** an answer right? (Just asking because you are new and didn't accept an answer to your previous question also)..

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to do

Comment: @Harish There is a small "tick" just below the downvote symbol.Check that.. And being on Stackexchange and not knowing how to accept n answer- DID YOU READ THE tour PAGE?

Answer (score 3):

HINT: You can use the usual [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) approach to find the total number of solutions in positive integers. Subtract from that the number with $a=b$; half of what remains will have $a<b$, and the other half will have $a>b$.

The messiest part is finding the number of solutions with $a=b$. Suppose that $a=b=k$; then $c+d=26-2k$, and the possible values of $26-2k$ are $2,4,6,\ldots,24$. For each of these values it’s very easy to calculate the number of solutions in positive integers $c$ and $d$, and the numbers that you get can actually be added by a formula: you won’t have to do it by hand.

Comment: Yes. But I guess by that method one is not getting the answer.It is actually a prove that type question.I tried it in this way though

Comment: Should I even include 0??I guess no then one may get the correct answer

Comment: @Harish: I worked it out just fine that way. There’s no place where you’ll include $0$: you’re looking for *positive* integer solutiosn.

Comment: Ok then let me have a try